# download numbers on play store and play console different

Tags: android, google-play

I've had an app published on Google Play for a few months. I can see from the developer console that it's had mor 1500 downloads, but the number of downloads is +1 on Google Play
(as it is for all other apps).

Why is this? Do I need to configure something I'm not aware of?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It takes some time for the play store data to update. The time it takes depends on when the indexing of the play store data takes place.

You don't need to configure anything. You just need to wait. It may take up to month for the data to update if there are issues with Play Store.